# Counting number of rows above since last occurrence

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

Spreadsheet question. I want to be able to look at a number in a cell and count the number of rows that appear above it before I hit that number again. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: A number *12345* appeared in *row=2*, *column=5*. What does this tell you? Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a formula, you will likely need VBA/macro to do it. You can find the first instance of a number with `MATCH` but that won't work for you unless you have a limit on how far back to look and know it would only occur once in say the last 10 rows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Imagine on different days of the week I have a different menu item. That's column A. In column B I want to list the number of days since that menu item last appeared. So lets say the Burger is A1 and in A5. In B5 I want to state how many rows (or days) since the last time the Burger showed up. This would be 4 rows (days) but I want to do it via a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=ROW()-MAX(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1)),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1)=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))`

You can see it working in this example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CHem3Y6ptvAjNX8ug9FcPBg3g28lrTPq_-hD5UnLgpw/edit?usp=sharing

This is now possible in Google Sheets as an arrayformula using the LAMBDA function:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),LET(l,BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,MAX(IF(INDIRECT("A$1:A"&ROW(x)-1)=x,row(INDIRECT("A$1:A"&ROW(x)-1)),)))),if(l=0,l,row(A2:A)-l)),))`

It will also work in Excel but you need to remove ArrayFormula and define the final row of the A2:A ranges, for example:

`=IF(LEN(A2:A100),LET(l,BYROW(A2:A100,LAMBDA(x,MAX(IF(INDIRECT("A$1:A"&ROW(x)-1)=x,ROW(INDIRECT("A$1:A"&ROW(x)-1)),)))),IF(l=0,l,ROW(A2:A100)-l)),)`

Comment: That works perfectly! Can you explain how this formula works?

Comment: The main part is a FILTER formula that returns the row numbers of the cells in column A (from row 1 down to the row above the formula cell) that match the value of the formula row of column B.  The MAX then returns the highest matching row number (i.e. the most recent instance).  This number is then subtracted from the formula row number to give the number of rows between the two.  I've tweaked the sheet to use IFERROR and return 'new item' rather than #N/A when a new value is introduced to column A

Comment: @ChrisHick, I can't find the FILTER formula in excel (2016). It is there in google spreadsheet though. Excel only shows FILTERXML.

Comment: as far as I know FILTER is currently only available in Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

A simpler attempt

```
=ROW(A12) - MAX(--($A$1:A11=A12)*ROW($A$1:A11))
```

You need to enter this formula as an array i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

`A12` is the current item

`A1:A11` are past days items

`--($A$1:A11=A12)` gives you all previous items that match the current item in the array form of {0;0;1;...;0} i.e. if the item matches it will result 1

`ROW($A$1:A11) gives you {1;2;....}` until the last row

`--($A$1:A11=A12)*ROW($A$1:A11)` turns all numbers in the second array to zero except where the item matched.

`Max` gives the index/row of the last matched number

`Row` - Max gives you the desired result.

[Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CHem3Y6ptvAjNX8ug9FcPBg3g28lrTPq_-hD5UnLgpw/edit?usp=sharing)